# Textbox auto compute

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have 4 textboxes 1 is autocompute

Texbox1 - Textbox2 and the answer will be divided to Textbox3 I only know how to subtract 2 textboxes only but I don't know how with 3 textboxes

code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" onchange='return Calculate();' ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" onchange='return Calculate();' ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox3" runat="server" onchange='return Calculate();' ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="AutoCompute" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Calculate() {

        document.getElementById('<%=AutoCompute.ClientID%>').value =
        document.getElementById('<%=Textbox1.ClientID%>').value - document.getElementById('<%=Textbox2.ClientID%>').value / document.getElementById('<%=Textbox3.ClientID%>').value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. it might works...

```
function Calculate() {
    var text1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Textbox1').value);
    var text2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Textbox2').value);
    var text3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Textbox3').value);

    if (!isNaN(text1) && !isNaN(text2) && !isNaN(text3)) {
        document.getElementById('AutoCompute').value = (text1 - text2) / text3;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about in textboxes do onchange ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you want, I think you forgot to put parenthesis around Textbox1 - Textbox2.  Like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Calculate() {    
        document.getElementById('AutoCompute').value =
        (document.getElementById('Textbox1').value - document.getElementById('Textbox2').value) / document.getElementById('Textbox3').value;
    }
</script>
```